# Any ideas about how to implement incremental backups to a MySQL database running in a controlled hosting environment like GoDaddy or Siteground?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I realize the answer to this question is "don't use a limited hosting provider."

But I've been very happy with Siteground and get a lot of value from them.

I have a virtual server with cPanel access along with SSH.

Siteground only offers 24 hour backups...with your option to restore the entire database - potentially wiping out 23 hours and 59 seconds worth of data.

Are there any ways to write scripts/cronjobs to automate incremental backups of MySQL databases?

Database is only 800MB or so...

Any tips, ideas, suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This might be a question better answered over on (https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: you can use binlog for this or have a look at perconas xtrabaclup

Comment: Many thanks for commenting. Siteground, the hosting provider, doesn't allow (or support) Xtrabackup).